# How to get Absorption cross section of Gaseous Ions for photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, plasma-physics, scattering-cross-section, absorption

How or where can I find the Absorption cross-section of Gaseous Ions? I have looked over the internet and can only find it for neutral atoms. Does it increase or decrease for ions?
I have found formulas but they include the imaginary part of the refractive index of the specific medium and I can't find how to calculate or get a relative order of magnitude for it even for plasmas. Scattering cross section will do too Please help.